# Can you use nextjs image component with canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am creating an image scroll component like the Apple Airpods Pro website. For this, I am using up to 750 for each iteration of this component. I need to draw the images onto a canvas, currently, I am using the standard JS - new Image() function to generate an HTML Image component to draw onto the canvas. I would like to incorporate the next/image caching functionality to ensure it runs as fast as possible. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

An `Image` component from `next/image` package is actually a normal `img` tag, what means that you can use it in `context.drawImage(image, x, y)` function.

Example:

```
// Canvas reference
const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)

// Create imgRef reference
const imgRef = useRef<HTMLImageElement>(null)

// Effect when image and context are loaded
useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current

    if (canvas === null)
        return

    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

    if (context === null)
        return

    // Get the `img` from reference
    const image = imgRef.current

    if (image === null)
        return

    // Draw the image to the context
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
}, [canvas, imgRef])
```

And finally add an `Image` component to your page like so:

```
<canvas
    ref={canvasRef}
    style={{
        border: 'solid 1px black',
    }}
></canvas>
// from `next/image`
<Image
    // attach a reference
    ref={imgRef}
    // source to the image
    src={'./myimage.png'}
    // Or import in a next.js fashion
    // import myImage from './myimage.png'
    // src={myImage}
    alt=""
    priority={true}
    // Hide it from displaying
    style={{
        display: 'none',
    }}
/>
```